# Why does my wireless keyboard fail when I plug in my WiFi adaptor?

Tags: usb, wireless, keyboard

When I run RaspBMC with Ethernet, the wireless keyboard works fine, but as soon as I put a WiFi adapter in, I can only use the keyboard for around 10 seconds, then it stops. I've tried 2 different keyboards with the same issue and tried different adapters, can anyone help me?

Also RaspBMC keeps running, just the keyboard stops.

Answer (score 11):

This sounds like a power problem. The Raspberry Pi can only supply a limited amount of current to the USB peripherals.

Try connecting the peripherals through a USB powered hub.

Answer (score 0):

Scott Hanselman recently [posted some truths and myths](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Top10RaspberryPiMythsAndTruths.aspx) about the Rasperry Pi and specifically said this

> One other point of note, NONE of my wireless keyboards or mice worked, and this is being talked about on the forums as well. The PI can handle only 100mA of draw on each of the two USB ports (get it? ~500mA for the PI and 100mA each for the two USB ports) and some devices pull more than 100mA. Some keyboards have little USB hubs of their own, like the Apple Wired Keyboard and they can't be driven by the PI alone. Expect to need a USB hub for any external drives or devices.

...regarding USB devices.